# WasapiLoopbackCapture to WaveOut

Tags: naudio

I'm using WasapiLoopbackCapture to capture sound coming from my speakers and then using onDataAvailable to send it to another device and I'm attempting to play the data sent using the WaveOut class and a BufferedWaveProvider and just adding a sample everytime data is sent from my client using the onDataAvailable. I'm having problems sending sound. The most functioning I've managed to get it is:

Not syncing the Wave format of the client and the server, just sending data and adding it to the sample. Problem is this is stutters very much even though I checked the buffer stored size and it has 51 seconds. I even have to increase the buffer size which eventually overflows anyway.

I tried syncing the Wave format and I just get clicks but have no problem with buffer size. I also tried making sure that at least a second was stored in the buffer but that had zero effect.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Are you sending the data across a network?

Comment: Yes I'm sending the data across the network. Using the Lidgren network library and just sending the data provided in the onDataAvailable event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncompressed audio takes up a *lot* of space on a network.  On my machine the `WasapiLoopbackCapture` object produces 32-bit (IeeeFloat) stereo samples at 44100 samples per second, for around 2.7Mbit/sec total raw bandwidth. Once you factor in TCP packet overheads and so on, that's quite a lot of data you're transferring.

The first thing I would suggest though is that you plug in some profiling code at each step in the process to get an idea of where your bottlenecks are happening.  How fast is data arriving from the capture device?  How big are your packets?  How long does it take to service each call to your `OnDataAvailable` event handler?  How much data are you sending per second across the network?  How fast is the data arriving at the client?  Figure out *where* the bottlenecks are and you get a much better idea of *what* the bottlenecks are.

Try building a simulated server that reads data from a wave file in various `WaveFormat`s (channels, bits per sample and sample rate) and simulates sending that data across the network to the client.  You might find that the problem goes away at lower bandwidth.  And if bandwidth is the issue, compression might be the solution.

If you're using a single-threaded model, and servicing each `OnDataAvailable` event takes longer than the recording frequency (ie: number of expected calls to `OnDataAvailable` per second) then there's going to be a data loss issue.  Multiple threads can help with this - one to get the data from the audio system, another to process and send the data.  But you can end up in the same position: losing data because you're not dealing with it quickly enough.  When that happens it's handy to know about it, because it indicates a problem in the program.  Find out when and where it happens - overflow in input, processing or output buffers all have different potential reasons and need different attention.